# How to Bind an CSS attribute to a Table Cell with Svelte

Tags: dom, svelte, svelte-component

I understand that with Svelte (or any other framework) it's not a good idea to access the DOM directly, eg. `document.getElementById` and then do something over it. I have a non-dynamic table that is already on a page as a Svelte component then I also have the following data: an array representing the table row's cells (let's say I have 5 cells per row) and also another array where each element has the index number where I must add a CSS attribute `active='1'` in the correspondent table cell.

ex.: `arrIdxs = [1,3,4]` and `arrCells = [a,b,c,d,e]`

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td active="1">b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td active="1">d</td>
<td active="1">e</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What is a good way to accomplish that?

Comment: I do not understand your CSS. But you can add a use directive for every td. Something like: use:setActive={arrIds}. The use function can access the node (dom) to update your td. If you need to update your td style you can use: Object.assign(node.style, { ... some css here ... }) in the setActive.

Comment: didn't know about the 'use' directive ... will definitely check that! thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand the use case, but you would have to do something like this:

```html
<script>
    const arrIdxs = [1, 3, 4];
    const arrCells = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        {#each arrCells as cell, index}
            <td class:active={arrIdxs.includes(index)}>{cell}</td>
        {/each}
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    .active {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```